# Laravel error Class 'App\Exceptions\SymfonyDisplayer' not found

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

[image]

When I send request from mobile to webservice I got this error. I have tried to update composer and success to update, but the error still same.

> Class 'App\Exceptions\SymfonyDisplayer' not found

Do you have any idea what causes this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is pretty clear - literaly it tells you do not have `SymfonyDisplayer` class in `App\Exceptions` namespace (which most likely means lack  of lack of `app/Exceptions/SymfonyDisplayer.php` file. But you most likely wanted to use `Illuminate\Exception\SymfonyDisplayer`, so it means you forgot to add

```
use Illuminate\Exception\SymfonyDisplayer
```

or use full namespace while i.e. instantiating object of that class:

```
$x = new \Illuminate\Exception\SymfonyDisplayer();
```

the last and less possible reason is that you wanted own `SymfonyDisplayer` to be used and it exists in expected directory but autoloader is unaware of that. This can be fixed by calling

```
composer dumpautoload
```

but you mentioned you updated composer packages so this step was automatically executed though.